# disabled value getting null in bean for p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to disabled department field based on employeeno.But,I want department value in bean.When,I using disabled value getting null in bean but without using disabled no problem...

```
<h:outputText value="Employee No"/>
  <p:selectOneMenu value="#{salarypromotionBean.salarypromotiondto.employeeNo}" id="emp" style="width:163px;">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="select" itemValue="0" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{salarypromotionBean.empid}"/>
  <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{salarypromotionBean.currentSalaryAmount}" update="salaryIncrement,empN,empDoj,basic,da,empNewDesig,commonSalaryIncrement"/>
  </p:selectOneMenu>

 <h:outputText value="Department" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{salarypromotionBean.salarypromotiondto.department}" id="empDept"  disabled="#{salarypromotionBean.designationDiaspleValue}" 
     style="width:163px;">
   <f:selectItems value="#{salarypromotionBean.deptname}" />
   </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Are you sure that #{salarypromotionBean.designationDiaspleValue} dosn't return "true" and by that disabling the selectOneMenu?

Comment: Emil Kaminski:Yeah sure #{salarypromotionBean.designationDiaspleValue} value get true that's why selectOneMenu get disabled and also i want disabled value in bean.But,value getting null in bean when disabled....

Comment: I'm sorry it's hard to understand your question. So instead of a null, you want to parse the value "Disabled" to your bean, when the selectOneMenu is disabled?

Comment: @ArunRaj JSF will not process a component with `disabled="true"`. This is why the value is null when the department dropdown is disabled. You should just use the value that's already set in the backing bean as `#{salarypromotionBean.salarypromotiondto.department}` when the element is disabled

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```html
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{salarypromotionBean.salarypromotiondto.department}" id="empDept"  rendered="#{!salarypromotionBean.designationDiaspleValue}" 
     style="width:163px;">
   <f:selectItems value="#{salarypromotionBean.deptname}" />
 </p:selectOneMenu>

<p:inputText value="#{salarypromotionBean.salarypromotiondto.department}" readonly="true" rendered="#{salarypromotionBean.designationDiaspleValue}"/>
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain why this is a solution